# Call .netcore2.1 library from .net 4.7.2 winform application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1, .net-4.7.2

We have a legacy winform application that includes a couple of 4.7.2 library projects. I have been given a task of making a call to a .netcore2.1 library.

The .netcore2.1 library lives in an aspnetcore2.1 project along with some other .netcore2.1 libraries. I have been trying to call the method in the .netcore2.1 library but it keeps failing with the following error. Can anyone point me in the right direction or just take me out of my misery :(

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: have you tried changing it to .NET standard instead of net core?

Comment: Hey @GlynnHurrell. Thanks but if I change the .netcore library to netstandard won't I have to do that for all my libraries in the aspnetcore project?

Comment: Potentially if you need to use more than the one in your framework project.  .NET standard is designed to be common between framework, core and other frameworks so if your requirement is to be able to use your class librarys between both, they'll need to be .NET standard as .NET core projects are not supported in framework

Comment: Thanks @GlynnHurrell. So what you are saying is I cannot call .netcore2.1 from .netstandard2.0(or a .net472 library) and the only way to have them communicate is converting all my .netcore projects to .netstandard? Unfortunately that is not an option for us so it looks like we will have to come up with another solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: So in general your class libraries should target .NET standard which you can then reference in your .NET Core,Framework and Xamarin apps.  Depending on how complex you class libraries are, there's a reasonable chance you can change the target type from netcore2.1 to .NET Standard 2X without having to make any amendments, as the APIs are very similar.